# Bengali unicode rendering problem during generating pdf from Jasper Studio (TIBCO Jaspersoft Studio)

Tags: jasper-reports

I am trying to create pdf in Bengali language using jasper studio (TIBCO Jaspersoft® Studio 6.6.0 in Ubuntu 16.04)

Below is My Jrxml properties and style:

```
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="Sample DB"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.awt.ignore.missing.font" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.encoding" value="Identity-H"/>
    <style name="Base" isDefault="true" fontName="SolaimanLipi" fontSize="18" pdfFontName="/home/shaon/Downloads/SolaimanLipi_20-04-07.ttf" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
```

This is showing correct preview in jasper studio:
[image: Jasper report studio preview]

But when I export pdf, bengali font gets distorted:
[image: PDF exported from Jaspersoft studio]

What am I doing wrong here? Any suggestion ?

Comment: You should use font extensions

Comment: Yes, I have created jar using jasper studio and added that jar in jasper studio java build path .Which actually solves this problem of showing correct font in PDF when generated from this jasper studio.